# Find the radius of the largest circle centered at the origin so that $u$ is continuous

Tags: continuity, circles

Consider the function $$u(x,y)=\tan\left(xy+x+y+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

I want to find the radius of the largest circle about the origin in which $u$ is continuous.

My first thought is to consider where the closest discontinuities to the origin are. These are at $$xy+x+y+\frac{\pi}{4}=-\frac{\pi}{2} \text{ and } xy+x+y+\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from this point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). With Wikipedia notation:
\begin{align}
&f(x,y)=-(x^2+y^2)
\end{align}
If you maximize $f$, then you minimize the distance to origin.

The points $(x,y)$ are subjected to the condition:
\begin{align}
&g(x,y)=xy+x+y+\frac{3\pi}{4}=0\\
\text{or}\quad &g(x,y)=xy+x+y-\frac{\pi}{4}=0
\end{align}

By the end, you obtain the points $(x_0,y_0)$ of the curve $g=0$ which are closest to the origin, and the radius will be $r_0=\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}$